# Android Studio doesn't accept Android SDK Location

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I've got a couple of years of Java experience but i'm new to Android Development. I installed Android Studio and on first launch it offers me to specify Android SDK Location in Settings/System Settings/Android SDK.

Android SDK is in `C:\Program Files\AndroidSdk` - so I:

- Click Edit
- Specify path `C:\Program Files\AndroidSdk`
- Click Next
- Then in Verify Setting menu button 'Next' is inactive so I click Finish
- I'm back in Setting with same red message "Specify Android SDK Location".

N.B. I specified `ANDROID_HOME = C:\Program Files\AndroidSdk`
and added `C:\Program Files\AndroidSdk\tools and C:\Program Files\AndroidSdk\tools\bin` in PATH.
Maybe you have any idea why it doesn't take my SDK Location?

Answer (score 1):

After you open Studio. Goto File->Project Structure

Then specify the correct SDK location.

[image]

You can verify in terminal or cmd whether the path you are providing there is actually reachable on your system. If not, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem! At first launch SDK Manager of Android Studio offers to install Android SDK on your PC, for this - specify EMPTY folder. I thought i had to give him the path to already existing SKD (non-empty folder) - that was the problem.
After specifying empty folder, everything had been installed successfully and seems to work fine.